# How do I highlight the output of grep / ag / ack tools in asciidoc

Tags: asciidoc

I'd like the output from asciidoc to look something like it does in the terminal. I could attach a screenshot as image, but I think highlighting the text is preferable.

```
// asciidoc source file
[source,XXX]
----
/home/neale/.zcompdump:670:4:'mhpath' '_mh'
/home/neale/.zcompdump:855:4:'pmpath' '_perl_modules'
/home/neale/.zcompdump:858:5:'podpath' '_perl_modules'
/home/neale/.zcompdump:1151:7:'tracepath' '_tracepath'
/home/neale/.zcompdump:1152:7:'tracepath6' '_tracepath'
/home/neale/.zcompdump:1482:11:'-value-,*path,-default-' '_directories'
/home/neale/.zcompdump:1483:11:'-value-,*PATH,-default-' '_dir_list'
/home/neale/.zcompdump:1484:23:'-value-,RUBY(LIB|OPT|PATH),-default-' '_ruby'
----
```

Is there some value of XXX that looks something like this? I have highlighting working for other languages (with local styles) generating pdfs (via a2x)

[image]